# The principle of conventional four-level diode-clamped inverter

Tags: inverter

Here is a four-level diode-clamped inverter (only one phase shown.)

I am confused why this kind of circuit it called 'diode clamped' inverter. How do the two diodes work here?

I know the working principle of a three level inverter，but I am not clear about the working principle of a four-level inverter. Can anyone tell me how this circuit works?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused why this kind of circuit it called 'diode clamped' inverter. How do the two diodes work here?

The purpose of the clamp diodes is to allow the load to back-feed the supply with current if necessary. Some loads are *reactive* which means they store some energy during part of an AC cycle, and want to return that stored energy to the power supply during other parts of the AC cycle. Another way to say the same thing is to say that the current and voltage are not in phase with one another.  Capacitors and inductors are examples of reactive loads.

[image]

(Image from [Reactive Power in Inductor and Capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/212983/reactive-power-in-inductor-and-capacitor.))

Comment: What's the difference between flyback diodes and clamp diodes?